# Is it possible to Ballerina program using 'eval' function

Tags: ballerina

I need to write a Ballerina code that receives a string from another program that contains code for a Ballerina function, and then `eval` it so I can actually call it.

Is this possible in Ballerina?

Answer (score -1):

Ballerina doesn't support dynamic code loading.

Comment: I'm coming here from the LQA queue and I'm a bit confused. Is this supposed to be a canonical dupe target? If so then I think you ought to give at least a bit more information, explanation, and citations. Right now this post is pretty low quality.